# Does it matter if i'm going from a 802.3af Ethernet switch port to a 802.3ab mesh router port?

Tags: power-over-ethernet

So from my modem i am using a Ethernet Switch with 4 PoE ports. I plan to connect it to a COVR D Link router and was wondering if it was compatible with the PoE. The data sheet says it's standards are IEEE 802.3i, IEEE 802.3u, and IEEE 802.3ab. The switch has 802.3af PoE ports and was wondering if it would work. Thanks for the help.

​

This is the Ethernet Switch - https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/switches/soho-ethernet-switches/GS308P.aspx#tab-techspecs

​

This is the Mesh Router - http://ca.dlink.com/products/connect/dual-band-whole-home-mesh-wi-fi-system-2pack/

Answer (score 2):

802.3af (Power over Ethernet) is not in any way related to 802.3i (10 Mbps Ethernet), 802.3u (100 Mbps Ethernet) or 802.3ab (Gigabit Ethernet) - other than all being part of the same group of Ethernet standards called IEEE 802.3.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3

The specifications of this access point don’t say anything that would suggest it can be powered by PoE. In fact, it seems it takes an AC cord that plugs directly in to your wall for “100 to 240 volts.”

You need to search for a device that specifically supports 802.3af Power over Ethernet. If the device says, “passive PoE” or “802.3at PoE” it will not work with your switch.

Answer (score 0):

IEEE 802.3 *xx* are amendments to the original standard. These amendments cover very different aspects - physical layer variants from 10BASE-T to 400GBASE-DR4 mostly, but also stuff like PoE. There's a pretty complete list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3).

The IEEE PoE standards (802.3af, 802.3at and the upcoming 802.3bt) are carefully designed to not supply any power to devices not compatible with it. So, you don't have to worry connecting a PoE port to a device not supporting or requiring it.